# "tel:" URLs lead to error page on non-mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, phone-number

On [this](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html) site, I have a link to a phone number for mobile devices in the top right corner where the mobile number is displayed. On desktops, when clicking on this link Chrome just ignores the link but firefox and internet explorer redirect to an error page.

HTML:

```
<a href="tel:+491796737741" class="contact-info" ></a>
```

CSS:

```
#header .contact-info { width: 293px; height: 133px; display: block; float: right; cursor: pointer; background: url(contact-info.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent; margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 110px; }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This german-language blog](http://blog.linkwerk.com/2011/04/telefon-links-fur-smartphones-desktopfreundlich/) shows a neat workaround that'll work with CSS3-capable browsers. First, you make your `tel:` links look like normal text by default:

```
a[href^="tel"]:link,
a[href^="tel"]:visited, 
a[href^="tel"]:hover {
    text-decoration:    none;
    color: #000;
}
```

Then, you give them link-like styling, but on mobile devices only:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  a[href^="tel"]:link,
  a[href^="tel"]:visited,
  a[href^="tel"]:hover {
      text-decoration:    underline;
      color: blue;
   }
}
```

This has several caveats:

- It won't work with ancient desktop browsers (IE7 and such) - you'd have to give each `tel:` link a specific `class` for this to work with all browsers (instead of relying on the CSS3 `href^="tel"` bit)
- It won't *remove* the link behaviour, just hide it a bit. Of course, you can easily completely hide `tel:` links as well, by setting `display: none` by default and `display: inline` on mobile devices
- It will show `tel:` links on any mobile device, regardless whether they're capable of handling the phone number or not.

Comment: Actually, if you specify `pointer-events:none` on the link for desktop browsers, it *will* remove the link behaviour. :-)

Comment: Screen width isn't a good litmus test for determining if the device is capable of making phone calls.  Also, it's a poor use of media queries to undo styles, then redo styles inside of a media query.  Just undo them inside of the reverse media query.  You end up with less CSS that does the same thing.

Comment: @cimmanon yeah, it's a very limited solution, and I'd like to see others compete with it (namely, a JS/jQuery-based mobile detection that prepares the links on document load). Re the reverse media query, those wouldn't get caught by older browsers that don't support media queries at all, would they?

Comment: The only old desktop browser in use that doesn't support media queries is IE.  The whole *mobile first* methodology is based around the concept that you're more likely to run across a mobile browser that doesn't support media queries than a desktop browser that doesn't.  Either way, mobile first wins in this instance because the CSS will be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to fix this is a bad idea since PCs are capable of adding handlers for `tel` links. For example, on my PC, Skype is set up to handle those links.