# html link to phone number gives error in firefox

Tags: html, anchor

I just discovered the html 5 way to make a link to a phone number like this:

```
<a href="tel:12345"
```

Works great on a mobile phone, but gives an error on a desktop browser like firefox. How to improve the user experience for the desktop user?

---

Update:

This question is already answered [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340935/clickable-tel-protocol-a-tag-in-firefox/46275930#46275930). There I added my new insights as an answer.

Comment: I think it's better to distinguish such a links using `a[href^="tel"]` in CSS, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391097/4344976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like no application assigned to tel: url on desktop.
One of variants you can parse navigator.appVersion javascript object to replace tel: link with skype: for example.
Take a look [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: thanks. I will look for a way to detect if a feature like tel: is not supported, then replace the anchor with a plain text field (span). I think there are easy ways to detect features.